# Affect return function to variable typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I Created a function that return a string

```
getTextContent (Id):string{
        var text = $(Id).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text();
        return text;
    }
```

and when I want to affect this function to a varible I get error

```
Invalid left-hand

dataDiv12 = this.gridService.getTextContent("#id"); //<= this is my error
```

Comment: where are you getting this error? how are you 'affecting' the function?

Comment: and what is this dataDiv12? how is it declared?

Comment: dataDiv12 is string

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in a simple example that shows how you create the `dataDiv12` variable and where your assignment statement happens? Also, please post the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure because you are not showing all the code, but I will guess this :

In your typescript class you have **dataDiv12** declared as a **string** and after that you are trying to "affect" / **assing** a value from that function to that Class property, which is incorrect syntax.

You cannot pass values like that inside the Class body, it needs to be in a **function**, or in a **set** / **get**, or at **initialization** of the property, or in the **constructor**.

Related to : [Error: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490399/error-referenceerror-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment)

So you **cannot have** :

```
dataDiv12 = this.gridService.getTextContent("#id");
```

You **should have** something like :

```
   set myDataDiv() {
        this.dataDiv12 = this.gridService.getTextContent("#id");
    }
```